# Binary scene voxelization using imageStore - problem

Tags: opengl, rendering, glsl, 3dtexture, voxelization

This problem has been haunting me for some time but I was busy with other things. I can't finish my GI technique (specifically occlusion step) without solving it.

I made a binary scene voxelization in a single pass. The result is stored in a `RGBA32UI` 3D texture. It is three way so I set three ortho matrices each for X, Y, Z direction. These matrices are centered in camera position and form frustum in cube shape. And in geometry shader choose axis based on triangle normal.

**First, what works - without binary voxelization** (but it's a waste of VRAM).
Here is fragment shader code of voxelization pass:

```
//gridDim - gridDimensions in voxels
ivec3 temp = ivec3( gl_FragCoord.xy, gridDim.z * gl_FragCoord.z) ;
ivec3 texcoord[3];

//correction of texture coord based on chosen axis and ortho matrix 
//(f_axis - 0, 1 or 2 from geometry shader)
texcoord[0] = temp;

texcoord[1].x = int(gridDim.z) - temp.x;
texcoord[1].y = temp.z;
texcoord[1].z = temp.y;

texcoord[2].x = temp.z;
texcoord[2].y = temp.y;
texcoord[2].z = int(gridDim.z) - temp.x;

imageStore(geometryGrid, texcoord[f_axis], uvec4(1u));
```

Drawing pass is done using instancing with cubes. The voxels are quite big because more of them results in a big framerate drop:

```
//vpVoxels is ortho matrix, worldPosCenter - center of each cube from vertex shader
vec4 geomCoords = vpVoxels * vec4(worldPosCenter, 1.0);
geomCoords.xyz /= geomCoords.w;
geomCoords.xyz = geomCoords.xyz * 0.5 + 0.5;

ivec3 index = ivec3(geomCoords.xyz * gridDim);

uvec4 voxel2 = texelFetch(geometryTexture, index, 0);
if(voxel2.r == 0u)
    discard;

normalColor = vec4(normal0, 1.0);
fragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

And it works:

[image]

**But if I change it to the binary version:**

```
//input - position 1-128, output: coded binary position as 1 in uvec4 format
    uvec4 encodeBinaryVoxel(int position)
    {
        // check for positioning to R channel
        position = max(position, 0);
        uint voxelId1 = (position > 32 || position == 0)? 0u : 1u << uint(position - 1);

        // check for positioning to G channel
        position = max(position - 32, 0);
        uint voxelId2 = (position > 32 || position == 0)? 0u : 1u << uint(position - 1);

        // check for positioning to B channel
        position = max(position - 32, 0);
        uint voxelId3 = (position > 32 || position == 0)? 0u : 1u << uint(position - 1);

        // check for positioning to A channel
        position = max(position - 32, 0);
        uint voxelId4 = (position > 32 || position == 0)? 0u : 1u << uint(position - 1);

        return uvec4(voxelId1, voxelId2, voxelId3, voxelId4);
    }

void main()
{
    ivec3 temp = ivec3( gl_FragCoord.xy, gridDim.z * gl_FragCoord.z) ;
    ivec3 texcoord[3];

    texcoord[0] = temp;

    texcoord[1].x = int(gridDim.z) - temp.x;
    texcoord[1].y = temp.z;
    texcoord[1].z = temp.y;

    texcoord[2].x = temp.z;
    texcoord[2].y = temp.y;
    texcoord[2].z = int(gridDim.z) - temp.x;

    //get z index of texture, each z slice has room for 128 bits (32*4)
    int indexZ = texcoord[f_axis].z / 128; 
    //get position in slice
    int bitZ = texcoord[f_axis].z % 128 + 1; 
    ivec3 index = ivec3(texcoord[f_axis].xy, indexZ);
    uvec4 current = imageLoad(geometryGrid, index);
    //encode position as binary uvec4
    uvec4 bit = encodeBinaryVoxel(bitZ); 
    //or operation with stored value
    imageStore(geometryGrid, index, bit | current); 
}
```

And read:

```
vec4 geomCoords = vpVoxels * vec4(worldPosCenter, 1.0);
geomCoords.xyz /= geomCoords.w;
geomCoords.xyz = geomCoords.xyz * 0.5 + 0.5;

ivec3 index = ivec3(geomCoords.xyz * gridDim);
int indexZ = index.z / 128;
int bitZ = index.z % 128 + 1;
uvec4 binZ = encodeBinaryVoxel(bitZ);

uvec4 voxel = texelFetch(geometryTexture, ivec3(index.xy, indexZ), 0);
uvec4 occupy = binZ & voxel;
if((occupy.r | occupy.g | occupy.b | occupy.a) == 0u)
    discard;

normalColor = vec4(normal0, 1.0);
fragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

The result:

[image]

As you see in the binary version it flickers and I have failed to find out the logic behind this (yet). However, voxel positions seem to be fine. I can render these voxels also by raymarching through the texture and this flickers too.

**EDIT**

I've made a simplest voxelization using only vertex + fragment and one ortho matrix in X direction (then it is incorrect but whatever), and store value only in first slice (my `gridDim` is less than 128 so it fits) and it still flickers:

```
ivec3 index = ivec3( gl_FragCoord.xy, gridDim.z * gl_FragCoord.z) ;

uvec4 bit = encodeBinaryVoxel(index.z + 1);

uvec4 current = imageLoad(geometryGrid, ivec3(index.xy, 0));

imageStore(geometryGrid, ivec3(index.xy, 0), bit | current);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the binary version you're doing an `imageLoad` and an `imageStore` on the same texture to modify it. This is a classic race condition: the GPU executes multiple threads of the shader in parallel, and there's no guarantee for those load-modify-store sequences to happen atomically. The operations from different threads can be interleaved, resulting in wrong data stored.

To fix it, you should use [`imageAtomicOr`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/imageAtomicOr.xhtml) to combine the bits you want to write with the bits already in the buffer without a race condition. For more information, see [this OpenGL wiki page](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Load_Store#Atomic_operations).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.  Yes, I'm kinda aware that such condition exists when using this operations. But I thought that it is just `or` (addition) operation so these operation will combine result in the same value no matter the order. just like 2+3+4 == 4+3+2.

Comment: In settings bits as occupied positions sense.

Comment: @narthex Yeah, it's a commutative operation, but that's not the issue—the problem is, the reads and writes from different threads can be interleaved. For example: thread 1 reads the initial value into a local variable, thread 2 reads the same initial value into its local variable, thread 1 writes a modified value, then thread 2 writes its own modified value that doesn't include the bits that thread 1 had set. So thread 1's contribution ends up getting lost.